# How to change case in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My table has one column that contain strings like:   `” HRM_APPLICATION_DELAY_IN”`

I want to perform bellow operations on each row on this column

1. convert to lower case
2. remove underscore `“_”`
3. change case (convert to upper case) of the character after the underscore like: `” hrm_Application_Delay_In”`

Need help for conversion. Thanks for advance

Comment: How can you perform step #3, if you've removed all underscores already in step #2 ??

Comment: SQL Server is good at performing set based operations against data. It's *not* good at string formatting. Can you not perform this formatting at a more appropriate layer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to achieve it:

```
create function f_test
(
@a varchar(max)

)
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
  set @a = lower(@a)
  while @a LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE '\'
  begin
    select @a = stuff(@a, v, 2, upper(substring(@a, v+1,1)))
    from (select charindex('_', @a) v) a
  end
  return @a
end
```

Example:

```
select dbo.f_test( HRM_APPLICATION_DELAY_IN')
```

Result:

```
hrmApplicationDelayIn
```

To update your table here is an example how to write the syntax with the function:

```
UPDATE <yourtable>
SET <yourcolumn> = dbo.f_test(col)
WHERE <yourcolumn> LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower('HRM_APPLICATION_DELAY_IN'),'_a','A'),'_b','B'),'_c','C'),'_d','D'),'_e','E'),'_f','F'),
'_g','G'),'_h','H'),'_i','I'),'_j','J'),'_k','K'),'_l','L'),
'_m','M'),'_n','N'),'_o','O'),'_p','P'),'_q','Q'),'_r','R'),
'_s','S'),'_t','T'),'_u','U'),'_v','V'),'_w','W'),'_x','X'),
'_y','Y'),'_z','Z'),'_','')
```

Comment: Replace 'HRM_APPLICATION_DELAY_IN' with your Column Name

Comment: I think it won't remove '_' from the strings if it is followed by some non alphabet like HRM_APPLICATION_DELAY_IN_1

Comment: @Seasoned : I updated the answer and it will now remove all the '_'s.

Answer (score 0):

For a variable this is overkill, but I'm using this to demonstrate a pattern

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'HRM_APPLICATION_DELAY_IN';
;with c(one,last,rest) as (
  select cast(lower(left(@str,1)) as varchar(max)),
         left(@str,1), stuff(lower(@str),1,1,'')
  union all
  select one+case when last='_'
             then upper(left(rest,1))
             else left(rest,1) end,
         left(rest,1), stuff(rest,1,1,'')
  from c
  where rest > ''
)
select max(one)
from c;
```

That can be extended to a column in a table

```
-- Sample table
declare @tbl table (
  id int identity not null primary key clustered,
  str varchar(100)
);
insert @tbl values
  ('HRM_APPLICATION_DELAY_IN'),
  ('HRM_APPLICATION_DELAY_OUT'),
  ('_HRM_APPLICATION_DELAY_OUT'),
  (''),
  (null),
  ('abc<de_fg>hi');

-- the query
;with c(id,one,last,rest) as (
  select id,cast(lower(left(str,1)) as varchar(max)),
         left(str,1), stuff(lower(str),1,1,'')
  from @tbl
  union all
  select id,one+case when last='_'
             then upper(left(rest,1))
             else left(rest,1) end,
         left(rest,1), stuff(rest,1,1,'')
  from c
  where rest > ''
)
select id,max(one)
from c
group by id
option (maxrecursion 0);

-- result
ID  COLUMN_1
1   hrm_Application_Delay_In
2   hrm_Application_Delay_Out
3   _Hrm_Application_Delay_Out
4   
5   (null)
6   abc<de_Fg>hi
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to show you my nice and simple solution. It uses Tally function to split the string by pattern, in our case by underscope. For understanding Tally functions, read this [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/).

So, this is how my tally function looks like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf_xt_tally_split](      
     @String NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@Delim   CHAR(1))
RETURNS  TABLE
as
return
    (

        WITH Tally AS (SELECT top (select isnull(LEN(@String),100)) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [name]) from master.dbo.syscolumns)      
        (
            SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Delim + @String + @Delim,N+1,CHARINDEX(@Delim,@Delim + @String + @Delim,N+1)-N-1))) Value, N as Ix
            FROM Tally
            WHERE N < LEN(@Delim + @String + @Delim)
            AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @String + @Delim,N,1) = @Delim 
         )
    )
```

This function returns a table, where each row represents part of string between @Delim (in our case between underscopes). Rest of the work is simple, just cobination of LEFT, RIGHT, LEN, UPPER and LOWER functions.

```
   declare @string varchar(max)
    set @string = ' HRM_APPLICATION_DELAY_IN'

    -- convert to lower case 
    set @string = LOWER(@string)
    declare @output varchar(max)

    -- build string 
    select @output = coalesce(@output + '_','') +
        UPPER(left(Value,1)) + RIGHT(Value, LEN(Value) - 1) 
            from dbo.tvf_xt_tally_split(@string, '_')

-- lower first char
select left(lower(@output),1) + RIGHT(@output, LEN(@output) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bellow two steps can  solve problem,as example i use sys.table.user can use any one

```
declare @Ret varchar(8000), @RetVal varchar(8000), @i int, @count int = 1;
declare @c varchar(10), @Text varchar(8000), @PrevCase varchar, @ModPrefix varchar(10);

DECLARE @FileDataTable TABLE(TableName varchar(200))

INSERT INTO @FileDataTable
select name FROM sys.tables where object_name(object_id) not like 'sys%'  order by name

SET @ModPrefix = 'Pur'


DECLARE crsTablesTruncIns CURSOR 
FOR select TableName FROM @FileDataTable
    OPEN crsTablesTruncIns
    FETCH NEXT FROM crsTablesTruncIns INTO @Text

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN


            SET @RetVal = '';

            select @i=1, @Ret = '';

               while (@i <= len(@Text))
               begin

                        SET @c = substring(@Text,@i,1)

                        --SET  @Ret = @Ret + case when @Reset=1 then UPPER(@c) else LOWER(@c)       


                        IF(@PrevCase = '_' OR @i = 1)
                            SET  @Ret = UPPER(@c)
                        ELSE
                            SET  @Ret = LOWER(@c)
                                   --@Reset = case when @c like '[a-zA-Z]' then 0 else 1 end,

                        if(@c like '[a-zA-Z]')
                            SET  @RetVal = @RetVal +  @Ret    

                        if(@c = '_')
                            SET @PrevCase = '_'
                        else
                            SET @PrevCase = ''

                        SET @i = @i +1

                end


            SET @RetVal = @ModPrefix + @RetVal

            print cast(@count as varchar) + ' ' + @RetVal 
            SET @count = @count + 1

            EXEC sp_RENAME @Text , @RetVal

            SET @RetVal = ''

    FETCH NEXT FROM crsTablesTruncIns INTO @Text
    END
CLOSE crsTablesTruncIns
DEALLOCATE crsTablesTruncIns
```

Comment: This is how you query worked for me: `Inventory_backup` -> `inventoryBbackup`, `BigTable_copy` -> `bigtableCcopy`. I.e. it duplicates every letter following a `_` by putting it instead of the `_`. Did you really want it like this?

Comment: Andriy M after your comment i update my syntax ,try new one if face any problem please inform me .

Comment: @AndriyM I agree this will not work. Noone has been rewarded any points for this answers for this question so far. Which answer would you choose ?

Comment: Well, thanks, but I think you should decide that for yourself. :) It's your question and your problem, so if you have your own  solution, just try it and see for yourself if it works for you the way you want it. To be honest, I only commented on your previous solution because it was short and I was able to spot a possible issue quickly. Your "revised" version would require much more time. At this point, I can only recommend you to take a closer look at other answers. Yours uses a cursor, and, in my opinion, cursors should be used as a last resort. Your problem *can* be solved without a cursor.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: I take it your question wasn't addressed at me, but rather at shamim.

Comment: @AndriyM I guess it was more or less meant for both of you. Shamim for comparing his long complex answer to a smoother solution. The part addressed to you, was because i wanted a neutral competant person to upvote the answer that was the best, to prevent shamim from choosing his own solution.